# Where is InterlockedRead?

Tags: multithreading, winapi, interlocked

Win32 api has a set of InterlockedXXX functions to atomically and synchronously manipulate simple variables, however there doesn't seem to be any InterlockedRead function, to simply retrive the value of the variable. How come?

[MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684122(v=vs.85).aspx) that:

> Simple reads and writes to properly-aligned 32-bit variables are atomic operations

but adds:

> However, access is not guaranteed to be synchronized. If two threads are reading and writing from the same variable, you cannot determine if one thread will perform its read operation before the other performs its write operation.

Which means, as I understand it, that a simple read operation of a variable can take place while another, say, InterlockedAdd operation is in place. So why isn't there an interlocked function to read a variable?

I guess the value can be read as the result InterlockedAdd-ing zero, but that doesn't seem the right way to go.

Answer (score 9):

The normal way of implementing this is to use a compare-exchange operation (e.g. `InterlockedCompareExchange64`) where both values are the same. I have a sneaking suspicion this can be performed more efficiently than an add of 0 for some reason, but I have no evidence to back this up.

Interestingly, .NET's [`Interlocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) class didn't gain a [`Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.read.aspx) method until .NET 2.0. I believe that `Interlocked.Read` is implemented using `Interlocked.CompareExchange`. (Note that the documentation for `Interlocked.Read` strikes me as somewhat misleading - it talks about atomicity, but not volatility, which means something very specific on .NET. I'm not sure what the Win32 memory model guarantees about visibility of newly written values from a different thread, if anything.)

Comment: @JS: Is there a specific reason you advised InterlockedCompareExchange64 (with emphasis on 64)? Interlocked.Read also works with 64 bits values, and says that "The Read method is unnecessary on 64-bit systems", which somewhat implies that InterlockedCompareExchnage (32 bits version) is not necessary when reading 32 bit values on a 32 bit machine.

Comment: @Remus: Good point about Thread.VolatileRead, although the documentation implies that you don't need to worry *at all* (rather than pointing to Thread.VolatileRead, which would have made more sense). @Sause: No particular reason for picking the 64 bit version, no. I think there's enough subtlety here that I wouldn't like to claim exactly what's necessary when in terms of trying to get away without doing any of this.

Comment: Of course, I've been assuming that Interlocked.Read will act as a volatile read in the first place. It never mentioned that in the docs, although I certainly hope it's the case!

Comment: I'm taking a risk here with 3k vs 70k plus, but I thought that there wasn't anything too special in the interlocked classes.  The reason they have that name is that because of the X86 architecture the interlocked operations of add and compare etc execute instructions that are guaranteed to complete atomically before a thread switch.  Hence they are "interlocked" because they run in parallel in the processor pipeline.  I'm fairly sure the docs also say that interlocked is not guaranteed away from a X86 processor. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbhbke0y.aspx

Comment: What do you mean by "not guaranteed away"? I certainly hope it's guaranteed to behave properly...

Answer (score 7):

I think that your interpretation of "not synchronized" is wrong.  Simple reads *are* atomic, but you have to take care of reordering and memory visibility issues yourself. The former is handled by using fence instructions at appropriate places, the latter is a non-issue with read (but a potential concurrent write has to ensure proper visibility, which Interlocked functions *should* do *if* they map to LOCKED asm instructions).

Comment: @zvrba: I think that what I call synchronized (actually, what MSDN calls synchronized) is what you call reordered. Anyway, I don't really see what the bottom line here is. Is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: This is an answer -- interlocked read (whatever that might be) is not necessary.

Comment: @zvrba: There is the issue of reading 64bit values on 32bit processors which is not atomic AFAIK. Hence CMPXCHG8B and Thread.InterlockedRead since you can actually read half of value pre-update, half post-update (ie. atomicity, not reordering).

Comment: AFAIK, bus transactions can be larger than 32 bits even on 32-bit x86. You could use 64-bit floating-point or MMX loads to read a 64-bit value atomically if the value is aligned to 64-bits. (from assembly. it's probably not possible within CLR due to many ugly casts that would be involved.)

Comment: The thread starting with this post may also be insightful:
http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.programming.threads/2006-03/msg00003.html

Answer (score 2):

The crux of this whole discussion is proper alignment, which is devined in Partition I of xxx, in section '`12.6.2 Alignment`':

```
Built-in datatypes shall be properly aligned, which is defined as follows:
• 1-byte, 2-byte, and 4-byte data is properly aligned when it is stored at
  a 1-byte, 2-byte, or 4-byte boundary, respectively.
• 8-byte data is properly aligned when it is stored on the same boundary
  required by the underlying hardware for atomic access to a native int.
```

Basically, all 32-bit values have the required alignment, and on a 64-bit platform, 64-bit values also have the required alignment.

*Note though*: There are attributes to explicitly alter the layout of classes in memory, which may cause you to lose this alignment. These are attributes specificially for this purpose though, so unless you have set out to alter the layout, this should not apply to you.

With that out of the way, the purpose of the `Interlocked` class is to provide operations that (to paraphrase) can only be observed in their 'before' or 'after' state. Interlocked operations are normally only of concern when modifying memory (typically in some non-trivial compare-exchange type way). As the MSDN article you found indicates, read operations (when properly aligned) can be considered atomic at all times without further precautions.

There are however other considerations when dealing with read operations:

- On modern CPUs, although the read may be atomic, it also may return the wrong value from a stale cache somewhere... this is where you may need to make the field 'volatile' to get the behaviour you expect
- If you are dealing with a 64-bit value on 32-bit hardware, you may need to use the `Interlocked.Read` operation to guarantee the *whole* 64-bit value is read in a single atomic operation (otherwise it may be performed as 2 separate 32-bit reads which can be from either side of a memory update)
- Re-ordering of your reads / writes may cause you to not get the value you expected; in which case some memory barrier may be needed (either explicit, or through the use of the `Interlocked` class operations)

**Short summary**; as far as atomicity goes, it is very likely that what you are doing does not need any special instruction for the read... there may however be other things you need to be careful of, depending on what exactly you are doing.

Comment: Wasn't it so that `volatile` protects only against "compiler generated" caches, like storing previous value in a register? Which means that `volatile` still may yield stale data due to CPU cache, and only using `Interlocked` reads would protect against the latter.